# Creating new legend using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, c#, legend

I am trying to add simple legend to the map.

I wrote some simple test code below to see what happens but it did not work.

```
var map = activeView.FocusMap;

            IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = activeView.GraphicsContainer;
            IMapFrame mapFrame = graphicsContainer.FindFrame(map) as IMapFrame;
            UID uid = new UID();
            uid.Value = "esriCarto.Legend";
            IMapSurround mapSurround = map.CreateMapSurround(uid, null);
mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame(uid, null);

            var legend = (ILegend)mapSurround;

            var legendItem = new VerticalLegendItemClass();
            legendItem.HeadingSymbol.Text = "served";
            legend.AddItem(legendItem);

            var legendItema = new VerticalLegendItemClass();
            legendItema.HeadingSymbol.Text = "unserved";
            legend.AddItem(legendItema);


            IElement element = legend as IElement;
            element.Geometry = envelope as IGeometry;
            graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);

            activeView.Refresh();
```

The legend I am after, must be similar to this:

[image: legend]

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Does the [Add Legend Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000006w000000) from the docs help?

Comment: @PetrKrebs yes, and tried this http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000006w000000 still nothing.

Comment: @PetrKrebs it keeps crushing on this code line: IMapSurroundFrame mapSurroundFrame = mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame((UID)uid, null);

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss what is the error you receive on crash?

Comment: Yes, I find it hard to understand why you wouldn't mention what exception you get at that particular line...

Answer (score 1):

You noted in comments that your program was crashing when you cast to UID like so:

```
mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame((UID)uid, null);
```

Your issue might be that you are casting to a C# System UID [such as this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uid.aspx). To rectify this, you will want to explicitly specify that you want to cast to the ArcObjects UID like in the snippet @PetrKrebs linked.

Try substituting the above code for this:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapSurroundFrame mapSurroundFrame = mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame((ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID)uid, null); // Explicit Cast
```

Though it requires more typing, it is always safer to explicity specify the full pathway of your references (in this case it is ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID or System.Windows.UIElement.UID) when referencing anything in programming as it prevents ambiguities such as these.

The compiler will sometimes catch an ambiguous reference, but not always. It will usually default to the System reference if there is an ambiguous reference and no warning/error is thrown.

Comment: Passing a different type would not compile at all..

Answer (score 1):

The following code (which is basically just an adapted sample from the SDK) works for me, but only if there are any layers in the map. Notice this is in line with ArcMap user interface, which does not allow you to insert the legend when no layers are in the map.

```
private void AddLegendForMap(IMap map, IPageLayout pageLayout, double xInPageUnits, double yInPageUnits, double widthInPageUnits)
{
    if (map == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("map");
    if (pageLayout == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("pageLayout");

    var layoutGraphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer)pageLayout;
    var mapFrame = layoutGraphicsContainer.FindFrame(map) as IMapFrame;

    if (mapFrame == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Map frame for given map was not found on the page layout.");
    }

    var legendUid = new UIDClass {Value = "esriCarto.Legend"};

    var legendMapSurroundFrame = mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame(legendUid, null);
    var legendMapSurround = legendMapSurroundFrame.MapSurround;

    double widthInPoints = 0;
    double heightInPoints = 0;

    ((IQuerySize)legendMapSurround).QuerySize(ref widthInPoints, ref heightInPoints);
    var widthToHeightRatio = widthInPoints / heightInPoints;

    var heightInPageUnits = widthInPageUnits * widthToHeightRatio;

    var envelope = new EnvelopeClass();
    envelope.PutCoords(xInPageUnits, yInPageUnits, xInPageUnits + widthInPageUnits, yInPageUnits + heightInPageUnits);

    ((IElement)legendMapSurroundFrame).Geometry = envelope;

    layoutGraphicsContainer.AddElement((IElement)legendMapSurroundFrame, 0);

    ((IActiveView)pageLayout).PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);
}
```