# Creating a Legend with arcpy and comtypes

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, legend, comtypes

I am relatively new working with python and arcobjects. Under normal limitations I know that you cannot create a Legend or any arcobject with arcpy.mapping. Is there a generic example of creating a legend or an arcobject using comtypes to get me in the right direction?

I am trying to create as script to automate several maps and export them to jpg after. (All the code is figured out outside the codeblocks with comtypes)

I was able to figure out (with some search) how create a MXD but not sure which arcobjects to be replace for creating a legend with CreateObject.

```
import arcpy, os
from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject
from Snippets import GetStandaloneModules, InitStandalone

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\foo"
wksp = arcpy.env.workspace

# Code that is out of the scope of the question

# Get the Carto module
esriCarto = GetModule(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\com\esriCarto.olb")


for boro in boros:
    # Create a map document object
    mxdobj = CreateObject(esriCarto.MapDocument, interface=esriCarto.IMapDocument)
    # Create a new borough mxd with mapping.MapDocument
    print "Creating Wifi_{}.mxd".format(boro)
    path = r"{}\Wifi_{}.mxd".format(wksp,boro)
    print path
    # Creates mxd
    mxdobj.new(path)
    #delete obj
    del mxdobj

# Rest of the code
```

Comment: There's a few examples on this site, have a search for python and ArcObjects, a good one is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142734/arcobjects-python-add-jpg-to-layout which deals with similar objects to legend objects. If you're not already familiar with ArcObjects have a read of this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129456/guidelines-for-using-arcobjects-from-python/150711#150711 about how to read the ArcObjects documentation to find your way from one object to another.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to code using python? If you are using ArcObjects it will be easier in VB or C#?  Unless you are trying to tie everything up into the geo-processing framework? Just curious?

Comment: This is a project I am working on for my GIS programming class. I know it would be easier for doing ArcObjects in .net but the class was run in python. I would like to know how to do this so I can use it for my thesis proposal I have to write soon as well.

Comment: And for an arcobjects approach: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73167/59

Comment: Thanks. That did help me figure out a few more things on what I needed to do even though I found the Arcobjecs API for this a bit confusing vs than the arcpy's API